# Why it is appending string not appending the string value?

Tags: jquery

In demo user scroll to top it prepend the text(string value) .But it prepand the string.
http://jsfiddle.net/G6jJS/12/

```
$("#fullContainer").scroll(function () {
    // top
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
       alert("up");
      var stringLoad ="page_"+i--;
       $( "<div id='"+stringLoad+"'>" +stringLoad+ "</div>").prependTo($("#fullContainer"));
    }

    if ($('this').scrollTop() >= $('this')[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) { 
       alert("down");
    }
});
```

Comment: what you wanted to do?

Comment: Can you be more clear please ?

Comment: I think you need to read the docs again, because your demo is working as one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a variable name dynamically like that, use an array

```
var pages = [page_1, page_2, page_3, page_4];

$('#fullContainer').html(pages.pop());

$("#fullContainer").scroll(function () {
    // top
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0 && pages.length) {
        console.log("up");
        var stringLoad = "page_" + pages.length;
        $("<div id='" + stringLoad + "'>" + pages.pop() + "</div>").prependTo($("#fullContainer"));
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) {
        console.log("down");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Gbd3z/)

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [Array.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Answer (score 1):

Use `window[stringload]` to get the page_x variable and declare the pages as global variables.

```
   $( "<div id='"+stringLoad+"'>" +window[stringLoad]+ "</div>").prependTo($("#fullContainer"));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6jJS/15/)